Case when,$∆,∆_1,∆_2∆_3=0$(Cramer's rule)
Using cramer's rule we in 3 variables and 3 equations we get the solutions as
$x∆=∆_1,y∆=∆_2,z∆=∆_3$,(1)
Now consider the case when I get $∆=0$, now if any of $∆_i≠0,(i=1,2,3)$ then I have no solution
Because in this case I get,
0 = some number
But if $∆_i=0,(i=1,2,3)$ so bassically I solved those 3 equations and 3 variables for $x$ and I'm getting $0=0$ (as per (1))
So those 3 equations are true for any x (same for $y,z$) so the given set of equations have infinitely many solutions
But then I thought of a case like
$$x+y+z=1,x+y+z=2,x+y+z=3$$
Here we also have $∆,∆_1,∆_2∆_3=0$
But clearly these are three parallel planes thus we have no solutions instead of infinite solutions
My questions is what's wrong in my reasoning also what is causing the case $∆,∆_1,∆_2∆_3=0$ to give rise to 2 cases where all 3 planes are parallel or all 3 planes have a line in common
Also another similar which  learned was

But clearly say if 2 lines from them are parallel still the condition holds but ofcourse they aren't concurrent

$(x,y,z)$ satisfy the original equations implies $(x,y,z)$ satisfy (1); but for $(x,y,z)$ satisfy (1) to imply $(x,y,z)$ satisfy the original equations needs the condition $\Delta\ne 0$.

Why one needs $∆≠0$ for $x,y,z$ to satisfy original equations given (1) holds.

I think you need to look at a text book for this. Basically the original equations are $Ax=b$, and by an identity this implies $(\det A)Ix=(\mathop{adj}A)b$; and if $\det A$ is $0$ the equations $0=(\mathop{adj}A)b$ tell us nothing at all about $x$. Your very good example shows how this happens in a specific case.

I haven't learned terms like adj, so I will try to think on it again after I finish with matrix also
